# What's the name of this theorem (multivariate polynomial factorization)?

Tags: factoring

I have proven the following theorem:

> Let $p(\vec{x}), q(\vec{x})\in\mathbb{F}[\vec{x}]$ be multivariate
>   polynomials in $n$ variables. If $q$ is linear and $q(\vec{x}) = 0$
>   implies $p(\vec{x}) = 0$ for all $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{F}^n$, then $q$
>   is a factor of $p$.

I do not know the name of this theorem.
I am wondering what theory(ies) or field(s) of mathematics this theorem relates to, and whether this theorem can be generalized.

In particular, the theorem fails if $q$ is only required to be irreducible rather than linear.
Take $p = (x^2-1)^2 + (y^2-1)^2$ and $q = (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2$ with $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried searching for a while, but could not find much (likely because I do not know what keywords to search for).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I discovered that this theorem is a special case of Bézout's theorem.
The generalization to irreducible $q$ is true as long as $p$ and $q$ share infinitely many zeroes.